# Aplicação web com cara de desktop

Tags: aplicação-web

Fala galera

Bom eu quero criar uma aplicação web, mas que possa ser executada no desktop(ou por url, mas essa seria a principal), ao abrir puxaria direto a "url" da aplicação, como uma aplicação web normal, porem seria como um software desktop, sem aparecer abas, url, sem parecer que é um browser, diretamente para aplicação, mas sem deixar de ser uma aplicação web.

Parecido com um atalho que agente pode criar na área de trabalho, passando a url e ao abrir sempre ir direto para aquele site, mas em vez de ser um atalho, abriria direto o software.

Exemplos que possa dar é como o jogo runescape que pode ser jogado via browser ou por uma versão "browser" para desktop, meu amigo comentou que a steam também é parecida.

Porem não sei como funciona isso, se eu preciso criar um "browser" novo, como se fosse um browser para minha aplicação ou algo parecido ou se eu crio uma aplicação web normalmente e somente moldo ela.

De forma que se pareça ao máximo um software desktop, mas a unica diferença é que ele roda na web.

Alguém que saiba, pode me orientar nessa?

Answer (score 2):

A maioria das bibliotecas gráficas tem componentes para carregar páginas web, com suporte a `css`, `sessão`, `javascript`, etc... Se for desenvolver em C++, a biblioteca gráfica Qt tem todos os componentes que você precisa.

Vou mandar umas fotos de exemplo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As imagens representam a mesma aplicação web, uma no browser normal, e a outra com uma `Webview` da biblioteca `Qt`

Comment: No caso seria como o componente web browser do windows forms e WPF(C#)? A unica diferença vai ser que em vez de rodar no browser rodara na plataforma onde foi feita? No caso eu usaria essa linguagem para back-end. Eu tinha pensado nesse componente, mas pensei que perderia a performasse comparado a uma aplicação "nativa" web, feita de forma convencional.

Comment: @Red Aplicação web já não tem performance, e é horrível em termos de interação com o usuário, então não faz sentido se preocupar com isso. Já fiz coisa do tipo, mas só por que era pra integrar um sistema legado em web, que não seria possível refazer naquela ocasião, em um sistema de verdade que fazia outras tarefas. Essa opção do Brumazzi é uma das mais comuns e mais rápidas para fazer esse tipo de improviso. E de quebra, você pode adicionar algumas funcionalidades que não funcionariam só do lado web, como usar identificação da máquina local, acessar dispositivos seriais, etc.

Comment: Essa é uma pratica muito comum, muitas empresas de aplicativos de celular usam uma webview para acessarem seus sites e outras fazem até jogos.

Comment: Passei uns dias pesquisando sobre o que foi me passado aqui. Então o "WebView" do "Qt" seria como o  "web browser" de várias outras como o chromium.  Mas eu não vou chegar a desenvolver "web" dentro delas, vou desenvolver normalmente e depois "moldar" o que já criei dentro do componente escolhido e possivelmente usar outras funcionalidades que venha me oferecer, pensava que teria como desenvolver direto(html, css, js dentro do mesmo) e rodar(web).

Comment: a framework `qt creator` tem um recurso para vc construir uma aplicação desktop e exportar para web, é só instalar o plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Algumas opções:

- [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/)
- [nw.js](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js)
- [Chromium embedded framework](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef), também conhecido por CEF (mais "low
  level" que as anteriores)
- existem outras alternativas, é só dar uma pesquisada

São frameworks que permitem que você desenvolva uma aplicação desktop utilizando tecnologias web (html, css, javascript), ambas as três listadas são basicamente wrappers em cima do chromium. Veja que estas frameworks são para desenvolvimento de apps *desktop*, logo a principio a aplicação inteira fica na máquina do usuário, porém você ainda poderia fazer algo como utilizar um banco de dados centralizado em um servidor com o qual as aplicações se comunicam/sincronizam (os apps desktop do spotify e da steam por exemplo usam o CEF para interface de usuário e todos os dados ficam em servidores externos).

Comment: Mas dessa forma a aplicação não deixaria de ser web? Perdendo as vantagens que ela oferece.                                                                    eu não curto muito sistemas web e como desktop não tem mais tanto mercado por algumas "vantagens" que a web oferece, pensei em unir o útil com o agradável, criando uma aplicação que tenha as vantagens de web e feita com suas ferramentas normais(html,css,js) porem muito parecida com desktop, mas sem perder nada que web pode proporcionar, flexibilidade etc. Sendo meio que hibrida, roda na web certinho mas complementos e acesso pelo desktop